# I want to get the posts of my channel with python telegram bot which the bot is admin in the channel

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

```
import random
import time
import telegram
from telegram.ext import *
from telegram import Bot
import json
import configparser
import tracemalloc
import asyncio


tracemalloc.start()

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")


Agent_TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN'
Bot_Status = config['Setting']['bot_status']
Post_keyword = config['Setting']['post_keyword']

print('Starting up bot...')

# Lets us use the /start command
def start_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('/start\n Shows this message again\n➖➖➖➖➖\n/setting\nShows your current setting\n➖➖➖➖➖\n/channels\nShows list of your channels\n➖➖➖➖➖\n/admins\nList of your admins\n➖➖➖➖➖\n/statistics\nShows a summary about your posts\n➖➖➖➖➖')

def show_setting_command(update, context):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    Post_keyword = config['Setting']['post_keyword']
    Bot_status = config['Setting']['bot_status']
    Agent_token = config['Setting']['agent_bot_token']
    if Bot_status == "True":
        Bot_Status = "Enabled"
    elif Bot_status == "False":
        Bot_Status = "Disabled"    
    update.message.reply_text(f"Bot status: {Bot_status}\n✏️To Edit bot status, use this command:\n/change_status NEW_VALUE(0 or 1)\n For Example: \n   /change_status 1\n➖➖➖➖➖\npostKeyword = {Post_keyword}\n✏️To Edit post keyword, use this command:\n/edit_postkeyword NEW_VALUE\n For Example: \n   /edit_postkeyword playstaion\n➖➖➖➖➖\nAgent bot token: {Agent_token}\n✏️To Edit agent bot token, use this command:\n/edit_agentbottoken NEW_VALUE\n For Example: \n   /edit_agentbottoken ABADSADNAJSDN12491248FASF")

def show_channels_command(update, context):
    f = open('Channels.json')
    Channels_list = json.load(f)
    print(Channels_list)
    Channels_list_str = ""
    for i in range(len(Channels_list)):
        Channels_list_str += Channels_list[i]["username"] + "\n\n\t\t\tID:" + str(Channels_list[i]["id"])+ "\n\n\t\t\tPostInterval: " + str(Channels_list[i]["Interval"]) + " Seconds\n\n\t\t\tPost Delay: " + str(Channels_list[i]["Repost_delay"]) + "Minutes\n\n\n"
    update.message.reply_text(f"You have added {len(Channels_list)} channels \n Your Channels list:\n {Channels_list_str}")
    

def add_channels_command(update, context) -> str:
    f = open('Channels.json')
    Channels_list = json.load(f)
    Channels_username_list = []
    for i in range(len(Channels_list)):
        Channels_username_list.append(Channels_list[i]["username"])
    args = context.args
    if args:
        channel_username = args[0]
        if channel_username not in Channels_username_list:
            Channel = {
            'id': random.randint(0,9999999999999999999999),
            'username' : channel_username,
            'Interval': str(5), #Senconds
            'Repost_delay' : str(1), #Minutes
            }
            Channels_list.append(Channel)    
            with open('Channels.json', 'w') as file:
                file.write(json.dumps(Channels_list) + '\n')            
            update.message.reply_text("Cahnnel added!")
        else:
            update.message.reply_text("Cahnnel already exists!")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("No Username provided")  


def edit_post_keyword_command(update, context):
    args = context.args
    if args:
        keyword = args[0]
        config.set("Setting", "post_keyword", keyword)
        with open("config.ini", "w") as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
        update.message.reply_text(f"The Post Keyword has been updated to: {keyword}")
    else:
        print("No keyword provided")   


def edit_agent_bot_token_command(update, context):
    args = context.args
    if args:
        bot_token = args[0]
        config.set("Setting", "agent_bot_token", bot_token)
        with open("config.ini", "w") as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
        update.message.reply_text(f"The agent bot token has been updated to: \n {bot_token}")
    else:
        print("No token provided")  


async def send_message(username,Interval,post_delay,bot_token,data):
    bot = Bot(token= bot_token)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=username, text=data[i]["message"])
        time.sleep(Interval)
    time.sleep(60*post_delay)      
      




def start_reposting_command(update, context):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    Bot_Status = config['Setting']['bot_status']
    Agent_Token = config['Setting']['agent_bot_token']
    f = open('Channels.json')
    Channels_list = json.load(f)
    Channels_username_list = []
    for i in range(len(Channels_list)):
        Channels_username_list.append(Channels_list[i]["username"])

    if Bot_Status == "True":
        bot = Bot(token= Agent_Token)
        update.message.reply_text('Reposting Started!')
        while Bot_Status == "True":
            f = open('posts.json')
            data = json.load(f)
            for i in range(0, len(data)):
                config = configparser.ConfigParser()
                config.read("config.ini")
                Bot_Status = config['Setting']['bot_status']
                if Bot_Status == "True":
                    for i in range(len(Channels_list)):
                    #  bot.send_message(chat_id=Channels_list[i]["username"], text=data[i]['message'])
                    #  asyncio.sleep(Channels_list[i]["Interval"])
                        for j in range(len(data)):
                            post_id = data[j]["id"]
                            print(telegram.Chat(156004022,str))
                            messages = context.bot.get_chat_messages(chat_id=Channels_list[i]["username"], limit=10)
                            # Process the messages
                            for message in messages:
                                # Do something with each message
                                print(message.text)
                        #     for message in messages:
                        #         print(message)
                        #     bot.send_message(chat_id=Channels_list[i]["username"], text="#"+data[j]["id"]+"\n"+data[j]["message"])
                        #     time.sleep(int(Channels_list[i]["Interval"]))
                        # time.sleep(60*int(Channels_list[i]["Repost_delay"])) 
                     # send_message(Channels_list[i]["username"],int(Channels_list[i]["Interval"]),int(Channels_list[i]["Repost_delay"]),Agent_Token,data)
                else:
                    print("Bot has been disabled")
                    break
                
            #     asyncio.sleep(5)
            # asyncio.sleep(10)
    else:
        update.message.reply_text('Bot Disabled')
    

def change_status_command(update,context):
    args = context.args
    if args:
        status = args[0]
        try:
            if status == str(1):
                    config.set("Setting", "bot_status", "True")
                    update.message.reply_text('Enabled!')
                    with open("config.ini", "w") as configfile:
                        config.write(configfile)
            elif status == str(0):
                config.set("Setting", "bot_status", "False")
                update.message.reply_text('Disabled!')
                with open("config.ini", "w") as configfile:
                    config.write(configfile)
            else:
                update.message.reply_text('Invalid Input for chaning the state of the Bot.(please enter between 0 and 1)')
        except:
                print(error)
                update.message.reply_text('Invalid Input for chaning the state of the Bot.(please enter between 0 and 1)شسبشسبش')
    else:
        print("No status provided")

def handle_response(text) -> str:
    # Create your own response logic
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    Post_keyword = config['Setting']['post_keyword']
    if Post_keyword in text:
        f = open('posts.json')
        posts = json.load(f)
        data = {
            'id': str(random.randint(0,999999)),
            'message': text,
        }
        posts.append(data)
        with open('posts.json', 'w') as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(posts) + '\n')
         
        return "message saved"
         
    return 'I don\'t understand'
        
def handle_message(update, context: CallbackContext):
    # Get basic info of the incoming message
    message_type = update.message.chat.type
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response = ''

    # Print a log for debugging
    print(f'User ({update.message.chat.id}) says: "{text}" in: {message_type}')

    # React to group messages only if users mention the bot directly
    if message_type == 'group':
        # Replace with your bot username
        if '@bot19292bot' in text:
            new_text = text.replace('@bot19292bot', '').strip()
            response = handle_response(new_text)
    else:
        response = handle_response(text)

    # Reply normal if the message is in private
    update.message.reply_text(response)

# Log errors
def error(update, context):
    print(f'Update {update} caused error {context.error}')


# Run the program1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater("6239735036:AAFrY2SmPsCrj389r1qYL2REvQIpSUC_dYc")
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Commands
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start_rp', start_reposting_command, run_async=True))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('change_status', change_status_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('setting', show_setting_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('edit_postkeyword', edit_post_keyword_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('edit_agentbottoken', edit_agent_bot_token_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('channels', show_channels_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('add_channel', add_channels_command))

    # Messages
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))

    # Add a handler for the input command
    # Log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Run the bot
    updater.start_polling(1.0)
    updater.idle()
```

This is a Reposter bot. it gets the posts that contain a specific keyword and saves them and reposts teh saved posts inside a channel.Then it has to delete the posted post and then repost it.
In the start_reposting_command function I want to get the messages of the channel, so I can delete the message before I want to repost it. But I don't know how.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is currently (July 2023) impossible to get message history for channels via Telegram Bot API.

The only way I see is to check every update to determine whether it is from the desired channel and whether it contains the keyword.

You can define [a custom filter](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Advanced-Filters) to process the update via the specific handler.